# Basic Vector-space exercize

Tags: vector-spaces

I've just begun studying groups, could you tell me if my answers to this exercice is correct ?

We supply $ \mathbb{R}^{*+} $  with laws $ \forall \ x,y \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^{*+} \ x+y=xy \ $ (intern law)

$\forall \ x \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^{*+}, \ \alpha \ \in \ \mathbb{R}, \ \alpha . x=x^{\alpha}$ (extern law)

Have we got a $R-vector space$ ?

Proove that (E,+) is an abelian group : $\\$

.Proove that + is associative :
$(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$ for all x,y,z in E
Indeed $(x+y)+z=(xy)+z=xyz=x+(y+z)$

. The law + has a neutral element n
$x+n=n+x=x \ \forall \ x \ \in \ E$ 
Indeed $x+n=xn=nx$ if and only if n=1.

.Each element of x has a symmetrical x' for the law +:: $x+x'=x'+x=n$ 
$xx'=x'x=n$ ssi $x'=\frac{1}{x}$

.And we show immediately that this a an abelian group thus  $(E,+)is a group$

.Now we proove that for each x in E : $1.x=x$ 
$1.x=x^1=x$

.For all x,y in E and $\lambda \ \in \ K \ \lambda.(x+y)=(\lambda.x)+(\lambda.y)$ 
$\lambda.(x+y)=(x+y)^{\lambda}=(xy)^{\lambda}$  which is equal to $(\lambda.x)+(\lambda.y)$  according to intern law

.For all x in E and lambda, mu in K : $(\lambda+\mu).x=(\lambda.x)+(\mu.x)$ 
On a $(\lambda+\mu).x=x^{\lambda+\mu}=x^{\lambda}*x^{\mu}$= $x^{\lambda}+x^{\mu}$ according to intern law

. $\lambda.(\mu.x)=(\lambda\mu).x$ 
$=( \lambda \mu).x=( \mu.x)^{\lambda}=(x^{\mu})^{\lambda}=x^{ \lambda \mu}$ so $(E,+,.)$  is  a $\mathbb{R}vector-space$ ?

Thank you

Comment: What is E ? do you mean $R^{*⁺}$ ? You also need to prove the closure of the laws, in fact: $x+y \in R^{*⁺}$, and same for $\lambda.x$.Apart from that, and the fact that the vocabulary you use is not the right one in English (intern/extern laws are called "vector addition" and "scalar multiplication", in general), your answers look OK to me.

Comment: Yes indeed $\mathbb{R}^{*+}$, thank you for the remark I will remember it ;-)